# Button Click Queued On Dispatcher

Tags: c#, wpf

When I click a button in wpf, is it the mouse click or the button click event that gets queued onto the dispatcher?  Is there a way to prove this?

This is currently what I'm doing to check all the posted operations.  But I can't tell if the operation came from mouse move event/backgroundthread/etc.

```
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Hooks.OperationPosted += (sender, e) =>
        {
            var operation = e.Operation;              
        };
```

Comment: Try using [snoop](http://blois.us/Snoop/) to try and see what your application is doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event will be invoked in the context of the dispatcher.

You can check this by reading `SynchronizationContext.Current`. It will be an instance of `DispatcherSynchronizationContext` whenever you are in a dispatcher context.

Comment: Which event are you referring to?

Comment: Are you saying mouse click event and the button click event are both queued in the dispatcher?  Could you elaborate a bit more?  I'm having trouble understanding.

Comment: Yes; they are both queued to the Dispatcher, so they will execute one at a time. This is true for all UI events: the mouse moving, the mouse moving over the button, the mouse button being pressed, the mouse button being released, and the button being clicked.

Comment: I understand that all the events are invoked on the context of the dispatcher.  What I don't understand is the interaction between the mouse click and how the button mouse clicked handler gets executed.  Like what are the order of events when a mouse click over a button occurs and how can I prove that order?

Comment: I don't believe it can be "proven", in the sense of "documented". WPF controls are techincally allowed to implement this in whatever way they want. It is *normal* for a MouseDown followed by a MouseUp to trigger a Clicked/Selected, but your code can capture messages so it's not strictly guaranteed. WPF has [some documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754010.aspx), but it mostly deals with keyboard inputs.